# How to show dynamic content in AngularJs Tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with tabs in which there is also a table, how can I dynamically show unique data for each tab?

[image: This hiw it's look like]

Code for tabs:

```
                        <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" label="{{tab.title}}">
                            <md-card layout="column" flex>
                                <md-tab-body>
                                    <md-table-container md-scroll-y layout-fill layout="column" class="md-padding table-scroll">
                                        <table md-table md-progress="promise" style="font-size: 11px !important;">
                                            <thead md-head md-order="query.order">
                                                <tr md-row>
                                                    <th md-column ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by tab.id"> {{ tab.content.Key }}</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody md-body>
                                                <tr md-row>
                                                    <td ng-repeat="tab in tabs track by tab.id" md-cell>{{ tab.content.Value }}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </md-table-container>
                                </md-tab-body>
                            </md-card>
                        </md-tab>
                    </md-tabs>
```

This how i get the result:

```
function getSummaryReportSchema(transactionid) {
   transactionService.getSummaryReportSchema(transactionid, orgName)
        .then((result) => {
            var idx = 0;
            result.forEach((element => {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(element.Values.replace(/\r\n/g, ''));

                vm.masterDetailResults.push(parsed);
                vm.tabs.push({
                    id: idx++,
                    title: element.TaskName,
                    content: parsed
                });
            }));
        });
};
```

And this is result which i get in vm.tabs - https://gist.github.com/Taifunov/c75d6d3d7ed6a32c2e9fdae24f24ae22

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is

Comment: Show different data in each tab table

Comment: That is your goal. What specific problem are you having achieving it?

Comment: I don't how to pass needed data to tab to show it in table. Coz as i do now it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong variables in your repeats. The first ng-repeat `tab in tabs` (shouldn't that be `tab in vm.tabs`?) sets the variable `tab` to use in your loop.

Then, when you are iterating the table cells, don't loop through `tabs` again - loop though `tab.content`.

```
<table md-table md-progress="promise" style="font-size: 11px !important;">
    <thead md-head md-order="query.order">
        <tr md-row>
            <th md-column ng-repeat="content in tab.content"> {{ content.Key }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody md-body>
        <tr md-row>
            <td ng-repeat="content in tab.content" md-cell>{{ content.Value }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```